# What happens to objects on serialization? How to keep Observers throuout serialization?

Tags: java, android, serialization

I do the following in one Activity:

```
    intent.putExtra("searchRegion", searchRegion);
    Log.d("AAA", "Puttin searchRegion: " + searchRegion.toString());
```

and on the receiving Activity:

```
    SearchRegion searchRegion = (SearchRegion) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("searchRegion");
    Log.d("AAA", "rcv searchreg " + searchRegion.toString());
```

The result is:

```
Puttin searchRegion: mypackage.SearchRegion@3b41ba0
rcv searchreg mypackage.SearchRegion@22655d14
```

I realized this when I wondered where the `Observer`s of my SearchRegion objects had gone after serialization.

I have two questions:

1. What exactly happens when serializing my object through the `Intent`? The object on the receiving end is not the same as the object on the sending end, right?
2. Can I keep the `Observer`s of an object throughout serialization with `Intent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What exactly happens when serializing my object through the Intent?

The data held by those objects, plus metadata about what the classes of the objects are, are written to a stream, then reconstituted from that stream.

> The object on the receiving end is not the same as the object on the sending end, right?

Correct.

> Can I keep the Observers of an object throughout serialization with Intent?

No.

Answer (score 0):

Serialization allows us to convert an Object to stream that we can send over the network or save it as file or store in DB for later usage.

As you know the objects are memory chunks so when ever you need to save it as file or send over network, you need to flatten it and when you want to use it you can deserialize it and yes on deserialization the object does not remain same. on deserialization a new object is created with same values as previous object.