# Effects on memory of passing serializable objects around

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-memory

According to CommonsWare's answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630639/what-happens-to-objects-on-serialization-how-to-keep-observers-throuout-seriali), when serializing and deserializing an object and passing it around via Intent, on the receiving end a new Object is created with identical values. 
So in theory, when passing an object via intent through 10 Activities, I will have 10 objects that are identical but will take 10 times the memory of just one object.

Thus my question: should I try to avoid passing objects around or keep them as small as possible to save on memory usage of my app?

Note: question is not about performance of the serialization process or serializable vs parcelable, but purely on trying to keep memory usage low.

Comment: pre optimization is the root of all evil

Comment: Good thing about android is that mostly one activity is visible at a time, and well mannered activities "should" release resources when they go out of view. Most of the time such objects will be garbage collected automatically.

Comment: It's simple, just don't clone objects if you don't need to. And if it's absolutely necessary, then start looking for other optimization alternatives.